# jQuery changing attribute of the element within an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I have a problem here, I couldn't set the attribute I wanted inside my table.

```
<tr id="ROW1" class="duplicate">
  <td>
    <textarea class="cl_text" cols="20" name="descriptions1"></textarea>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="cl_form" size="10" value="" name="expectedDate1">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="cl_form" size="10" value="" name="slxInput1">
  </td>
  ...
  ...
</tr>
```

I can change the attribute of the TD element but not those within it.
I need to change all those elements within the TD elements, it's easy to change the first and last elements but how about the others?
If possible, I just wanted to a loop that will do change all those attributes under #ROW1

EDITED:
I added my code that isn't working;

```
$( "#ROW" + Num ).each(function(index) {
    temp = $(this).children(":first").attr("name");
    $(this).children(":first").attr("name", temp+Num);
});
```

Comment: Please post your code (edit the question and add it).

Comment: You should browse through the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#ROW1 td").each(function(){
   $.each($(this).children(
$(this).attr(//put some attribute)
));
})
```

Comment: I somehow still need to add children() after $(this) to access the elements, thanks

Comment: This does not make much sense... `children` does not accept an argument.

Comment: Your right, I didn't notice that. It's just that I need to put the 'TD' element to make my script work that I didn't notice that part of the answer

Answer (score 5):

To change an attribute for all inputs and textareas in the table row:

```
$('#ROW1 textarea, #ROW1 input').attr('someattr', 'value');
```

Comment: Or if just the `td` have to be excluded: `$('#ROW1 > td *')` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

To get all child elements of `#ROW1`:

```
$('#ROW1').find('*')
```

Comment: But isn't the child elements of #ROW1 are the TD elements?

Comment: @MegaNairda: The `find` method doesn't get only the immediate children, but also children of children, so it will get the td elements and all elements inside it.

Comment: @Michael: No, what you refer to as "immediate children" are *children* and everything else are *descendants*... just like in real life. The children of my children are not my own children.

Comment: The problem with this code is that it includes also those table elements which I do not need to change the attributes. I only need to change the attributes of the elements within those elements.